# SAPUI5 Table drop down binding getting removed on table re-binding

Tags: xml, sapui5, jscript

I have created an SAPUI5 table, I am trying to get the element from row on button click,
For eg: My Table has 4 rows,
I need to get columns 1 and columns 2 values, and set them in column 3 and 4 after some calculations,
​I also have a drop down in my table, I am custom binding my drop down control in the table,
Now when I re-bind the table after calculations, my drop down binding is getting removed.

below is my code SAPUI5 view code,

```
<t:Table rows="{/}">
  <t:extension>
    <OverflowToolbar>
      <ToolbarSpacer />
      <Button
        icon="sap-icon://add"
        press=".onAddPress"
      />
      <Button
        icon="sap-icon://add"
        press=".onCalculate"
      />
    </OverflowToolbar>
  </t:extension>
  <t:columns>
    <t:Column>
      <Text text="Item 1" />
      <t:template>
        <ComboBox width="100%" items="{items1}">
          <core:Item
            key="{key}"
            text="{text}"
          />
        </ComboBox>
      </t:template>
    </t:Column>
    <!-- ... -->
  </t:columns>
</t:Table>
```

Here is my controller code for add row,

```
onAddPress: function() {
  var model = this.getOwnerComponent().getModel();
  var currentRows = model.getProperty("/");
  var newRows = currentRows.concat(this.createEntry());
  model.setProperty("/", newRows);
},
```

I am taking help from the following link : https://plnkr.co/edit/8YvXxk?p=preview

Below is my code for calculations and re-binding of table,

```
     var oModel = this.getModel();
                    var oTable = this.getView().byId("tbl_lineItemsList");
                    var data = oTable.getModel();
                    var len = oTable._iBindingLength; 

                    if (this._oViewModel.getProperty("/mode") === "create") {
                        for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                            var _qty = data.oData[i].Quan;
                            var _mtnr = data.oData[i].Matnr;
                            if (_mtnr === '' || _qty === '') {
                                Flag = true;
                                message = " Material or Quantity, " + message;
                                break;
                            }
                            matnr[i] = data.oData[i].Matnr;
                            qty[i] = data.oData[i].Quan;
                            tfilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Matnr", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, matnr[i]));
                            tfilters.push(new sap.ui.model.Filter("Quan", sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ, qty[i]));
                        }

        var mParameters = {
                    filters: tfilters,
                    success: function(oData) {
                        this.getModel("appView").setProperty("/busy", false);
                        if (oData.results["0"].Mesg === '') {
         var oModel1 = new sap.ui.model.json.JSONModel(oData.results);

                            if (this._oViewModel.getProperty("/mode") === "create") {

                oTable.unbindColumns();
                                oTable.unbindRows();
                                oTable.setModel(oModel1);
                                oTable.bindRows("/");
    }
}

    oModel.read("/TableSet", mParameters);
```

[image]

Comment: I see now that you're actually reading the data manually via ODataModel#read and then binding it via JSONModel. What was the reason for that? What feature was missing from ODataModel?

Comment: This question rather looks like the [XY-problem](http://xyproblem.info/).We don't have to re-bind the data when binding is done properly with ODataModel. I'm trying to prevent you from possibly reinventing the wheel with JSONModel although the backend protocol is OData.

Comment: I think it can be XY-problem in my case,
Actually my requirements are here,
1: Bind a drop down in the table based on parameters added by the user in the form. Your code worked for me.
2: Now Based on values of the drop downs, I need some calculations in the background (oData model ABAP side) and return the result set, that I need to bind in the table, as initially you can see empty columns above.
These columns will be filled based on values of the drop down.
Can you connect with me via skype or some other medium where I can show you my code adn working ?

Comment: I'd recommend to check the documentation topic [OData V2 Model](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html#loio6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2). There is also a section called [Function Import](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/6c47b2b39db9404582994070ec3d57a2.html#loio6cb8d585ed594ee4b447b5b560f292a4) which describes how you can bind the results you got from calling custom function.

Comment: I already know that sir, I can bind odata results to my table easily,
issue here I am facing is, when I am binding the odata with my table, the drop down bindings r getting null n void.
As I am binding the results after removing all bindings.